# Ending dynamic 2d array with blank line (enter)

Tags: c, jagged-arrays

I need to create 2D dynamic array in C with input like that:

```
3(spacja)21(spacja)11(enter) 
4(spacja)5(spacja)125(spacja)45(enter) 
1(spacja)9(spacja)4(enter) 
(enter)
```

Blank line have to end input, but I can't make it work.

```
  for (int m = 0;; ++m) {
    a = (float **) realloc(a, (m + 1) * sizeof(*a));
    a[m]=NULL;
    i = 0;
    while ((count = scanf("%f%c", &tmp, &follow)) > 0) {
      if (count == 2 && (isspace(follow) || follow == '\n')) {
        a[m] = (float*) realloc(a[m], (i + 1) * sizeof(float));
        a[m][i] = tmp;
        i++;
        if (follow == '\n') {
          n[m] = i;
          break;
        }
      } else {
        printf("Wprowadzono bledne dane\n");  // Wrong data has been entered
        EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] so others may compile and replicate your problem.

Comment: After the `for (int m = 0;; ++m)` loop `m` is lost (goes out of scope).  How does subsequent code use `a` without access to  `m`?  Provide detail about "I can't make it work".

Comment: Don't cast the result of `*alloc()` in C. "`realloc(a[m], (i + 1) * sizeof(float))`" has undefined behaviour for `a[m]` not null or a pointer previousliy allocated by `*alloc()`.

Comment: Loop must be taken endless until user input blank line. I got problem with stoping loop when that condition is done